# Is there a name for this percussive beat in the beginning of Jon Batiste's Freedom video and Pogo's Do You?

Tags: terminology, drums

After 00:06 in Jon Batiste's video *Freedom* there is a drum beat with six "notes" (I don't know the proper term) per measure, and Pogo's video *Do You* begins with almost exactly the same rhythm, except there's a seventh, unstressed sound at maybe the last sixteenth note before the beginning of a 4:4 measure.

While I don't think it's as historically significant as the [Amen Break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amen_break) it certainly sounds to me like it would have been used in other places as well.

**Question:**  Is there a name for it, or notable and/or first use?